# How to stop CTRL + keys affecting browser when using keypress events on page?

Tags: javascript

I am incorporating onkeyup and onkeydown events into my page.

I want to be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>... keypresses (right way through the alphabet).

This is fine, but whilst my page reacts to these key presses, so does the browser as these are browser shortcuts.

Is there any way to *block* the shortcuts on the page?

Comment: Try with `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: When I do that, the "enter" key is not recognised.

Comment: You're maybe using wrong key code. Look at http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes. `13` is Enter code. I don't know how `event.preventDefault();` can override enter, except you added enter shortcut in your JS.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for clarifying, add an answer and ill accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.preventDefault();` prevents default event action when key is pressed.

If you need help with key codes, look at http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes.

Comment: Actually its not working, can you post a JSfiddle showing how to use it? When I press ctrl+b it brings up bookmarks in browser... I have <span onkeyup=myFunction();return false;></span>

Comment: inside function I have event.preventDefault(); (and I meant myFunction(event);return false;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDroid/Xr8w7/ (a note: you need to click into the result, then press Ctrl + A)

Comment: hi thanks for doing that, I see how it works, but I am calling the JS from within the span, not by event listener, can you adjust for that case at all?

Comment: `<span>` can't get keyup / keydown. `<span>` is element which isn't focusable. That's why I used window as base. :)

Comment: Ah its ok, fixed it (span can be focussed btw!). It was some coding logic on my end :/ thnx for the help.

Comment: Aw, ok. It can't be focused really (at least in modern browsers). :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44811/discussion-between-zdroid-and-obv)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [jquery.hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) this plugin will do everything for you.

> jQuery Hotkeys is a plug-in that lets you easily add and remove handlers for keyboard events anywhere in your code supporting almost any key combination.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can take a look into https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys
I used it a while back and found it very good.

Comment: Does everyone need jQuery to make JavaScript work? Lol.

Comment: But driving a hundred miles is lot easier than running ! ;)

Comment: Lawl. Really interesting.